# Where to override SaveChanges() method with code generated from a template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to override the SaveChanges() method with my own so that I can record change details with fields like CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, CreatedOn, UpdatedOn, etc. My only question is... Where would I add this method if I am not adding it to my Entities Class? I know I am not supposed to edit this file, because it could easily be overwritten:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace DAL
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class GECICDashboardEntities : DbContext
    {
```

Where else could I override?

Comment: Can you not just created another partial class, named the same and add the override methods in there?

Comment: I will give this a shot! I just don't want to mess anything up with the DbContext, I am new to MVC and Entity.

Answer (score 0):

@JamesS had the answer in the comments.

"Can you not just created another partial class, named the same and add the override methods in there?"

I created the class file with the same class name, GECICDashboardEntities, and it ran my override method. Thanks!